# Django importing of module

Tags: python, django

I am just going through some Django code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

I have few question regarding this:

- This render thing how do we know this needs to be imported from django.shortcuts?
- Can we see render it lies in this folder django.shortcuts,?
- Where is this located on a drive django.shortcuts ?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - This render thing how do we know this needs to be imported from django.shortcuts?

The main way for you to know what these functions are by referring to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/). When you've used it several times, you'll understand what function to use according to the situation. Django has one of the best documentations I've seen for any project. The specific topic you're looking for is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/).

> - Can we see render it lies in this folder django.shortcuts,?
> - Where is this located on a drive django.shortcuts ?

Actually, if you want to see how it works, you can. Django library code is not in your project directory. It's in the `site-packages` directory. If you're using a virtual environment (which you should), `django.shortcuts` can be found at `<virtual_env_dir>/lib/python3.x/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py`.

However, if you want to find a function for a particular purpose, I recommend trying the online documentation first, before diving into the source code.

Kudos on being curious!

Comment: In a seconds earlier than me :) Nevertheless, I feel to mention that it could be helpful for OP to check on [this official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/) to get more familiar with the base concepts of Django.